# Validate data driven testing

Tags: text, selenium, validation

I got the code for getting the data from excel and den using in selenium.

My problem is that when i give invalid data in the text boxes those are also getting accepted!!
But when i checked by entering those invalid data in the same text box its not  accepting

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide little bit more details?

Maybe your test boxes have some client-side JavaScript verification which is not triggered when you are setting the values. You can try to use something like sendKeys or trigger the check with JavaScript